# npm audit EINVALIDTAGNAME

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, audit

When I execute npm audit in a folder with the project's `package.json` and `package-lock.json` I get the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'audit' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v10.14.0
4 verbose npm-session d5b5c65bd8e7ae03
5 verbose stack Error: Invalid tag name "[object Object]": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
5 verbose stack     at invalidTagName (/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:87:15)
5 verbose stack     at fromRegistry (/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:290:13)
5 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:77:12)
5 verbose stack     at Object.keys.forEach.name (/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:26:26)
5 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
5 verbose stack     at Promise.all.then.result (/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:25:25)
6 verbose cwd /home/user/projects/test-npm/CRYPTOSTORAGE/repos/crypto-storage/etc/approvalClient
7 verbose Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
8 verbose argv "/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/user/Downloads/node-v10.14.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "audit"
9 verbose node v10.14.0
10 verbose npm  v6.5.0
11 error code EINVALIDTAGNAME
12 error Invalid tag name "[object Object]": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If this would happen to only one project - but actually it does indeed happen to all projects that I've tried (~70). There is an internal registry, but I've both removed the local `.npmrc` and the one in home. Also the error I was getting then was a different one.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What *does* the package's `"tags"` property look like?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "lodash._maxpoolsize": {
      "integrity": "sha1-nUgvRjuOZq++WcLBTtsRcGAXIzQ=",
      "resolved": "https://repo.host.com/npmjs-npm-re/lodash._maxpoolsize/-/lodash._maxpoolsize-2.4.1.tgz",
      "version": "2.4.1"
    },
    "http-signature": {
      "integrity": "sha1-muzZJRFHcvPZW2WmCruPfBj7rOE=",
      "resolved": "https://repo.host.com/npmjs-npm-re/http-signature/-/http-signature-1.2.0.tgz",
      "requires": {
        "assert-plus": "1.0.0",
        "jsprim": "1.4.1",
        "sshpk": "1.13.1"
      },
      "version": "1.2.0"
...

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if this is the exact issue the author is hitting, but I ran into this error when I copy/pasted the contents of my package.json into package-lock.json. As I was searching through the JS stack trace, I realized that those files have different object formats and are not interchangeable.

This is likely your issue if `npm install` works fine, but `npm ci` and `npm audit` are failing with the above error.

Comment: I had deleted package-lock.json, then run npm install and then npm audit fix. And got similar error. Especially "nice" is that this error does not reference any file or any line.

Seems like a bug:
https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-passes-code-einvalidtagname-from-node-8-9-4/2304
https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-passes-code-einvalidtagname/4838